# How to load large amount of data to Xtrareport viewer in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, xtrareport

The asp.net website able to generate or load data into report viewer in Xtrareport if the file size below 10MB(after export it to PDF);but when more data is loaded, the loading panel loading forever.Then the error show in console of google developer tool was the Gateway Timeout 504.There is no issue when it run on the localhost but this issue occurred when run on live server. The code of Xtrareport will look like:

```
<dx:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="ReportViewer1" OnUnload="ReportViewer1_Unload"EnableTheming="True" Theme="Default"Visible="false" Width="100%"><Border BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="5px" /></dx:ReportViewer>
```

I had try to fix the bug by edit web.config file:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="30720" executionTimeout="3600"/>
```

Unfortunately the solution seem not work at all.

Comment: DevExpress offers some advice for speeding up report generation: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A2889

Comment: Additionally, with regards to ASP.NET report generation: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18541

Comment: The loading panel display forever and the report unable to loaded into the xtrareport viewer.The gateway timemout 504 error appeared after the period of time while the loading panel is loading.

Comment: Have you performed any profiling on your web application to determine what part of the report generation is timing out? It could be the Sql query that populates the data or it could be the report engine that renders the report. I think you will need to do some more research to figure out where the bottleneck occurs.